# Does Java include comments on the compiled code?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Well, the title is self-explanatory. I wondered this while compiling a project which has a lot of lines commented. It's a bit silly because the jar file wouldn't increase much (some bytes) but I'm curious if this could affect a program with a lot of code and comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would not affect the execution or performance (unless you have commented out the wrong statements :-)

But it *definitely* would affect readability. There is no reason to have large blocks of commented out code (in production), [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) is the way to go

<strike>See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123423/do-you-leave-historical-code-commented-out-in-classes-that-you-update) also.</strike><sup><sup>Question closed.</sup></sup>

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I'm just doing some basic stuff without using subversion or anything, but when I use such tools I will remember your advice!

Comment: The title made me curious about its content. The [original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123423/do-you-leave-historical-code-commented-out-in-classes-that-you-update) was deleted, no idea why. A link to *Do you leave historical code commented out in classes that you update?* can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140819230320/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123423/do-you-leave-historical-code-commented-out-in-classes-that-you-update#).

Comment: The link to "this question" no longer functions.

Comment: @mikebabcock looks like the other question is closed now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 20):

No, comments normally are stripped out in any language (not just in Java). They have no representative in byte code. What stays in there, is annotated stuff and such

Comment: Not all of them :-) In PHP you can actually reflect over the comments of a class or method. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php.

Comment: Well, PHP is an interpreted language. So your code is not compiled like in Java, C#, C++, ... If you use something like eAccelerator which stored the code in their compiled representative, you won't be able to use this functionality, as the comments got stripped out

Answer (score 4):

No, documentation isn't included in the compiled class file.

The javadocs can be generated with the `javadoc` program. All javadoc will be converterd to HTML.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not added.

However, you should consider to kill dead code (i.e. commented code, but also unused code). If you think that "maybe I will need that method again", simply delete the method, and if you *really* need this method some day, use you SCM tool (Subversion, Git, CVS or whatever) to retrieve this old code...

Comment: @XXL Commented code: if the code is commented, it means that it's not used anymore. So why keep it? (you can find it again with your SCM, that's its purpose). Dead code: same remark: if not used why keeping it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. No, you miss something.

Yes, you are right. In my opinion, unnecessary old code fragments that have nothing to do with the program should not be stored in the source code as comments.

No, you are not right, because you have not noticed the completely obvious things. **The old code as a comment may be evidence in matters related to copyright.** Simply if you remove the old code from the program before the code is exposed as open source (or given to the recipient), then there will be no trace of the old code and it will be more difficult to prove that it ever existed at all. Let's imagine that we have fragment A, which we replaced with a (much better) fragment B. By publishing the code with both of them we show that we are the authors of solution A and solution B. By removing the old code A, we lose the possibility of referring to the fact that code A was created by us. Even if A is worse than B, **it may still be good enough to want to protect our rights to it**.