# Can Java comments be seen by decompiling?

Tags: java, comments, decompiling

I was wondering if I put comments in my code and when someone tried to decompile it, if they could read the comments that I put?

Comment: "Sometimes I believe compiler ignores all my comments."

Comment: "Sometimes I believe the compiler is reading all my comments."

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032147/does-java-include-comments-on-the-compiled-code

Comment: Are you afraid of what people might read in there?

Comment: I add stuff about how my code works and I was gonna obfuscate it and if someone could read the comments, it would make it easier to deobfuscate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, comments are never included as part of the compilation process. They are typically removed in some sort of pre-processing, or first-pass stage.

Comment: Thanks, just was making sure :D

Answer (score 5):

Nope, comments are discarded by the compiler.

Comment: If your concern is to make it difficult for someone to figure out your code by decompiling it, there is also an option not to save local variable names in the compiled code. And if you really want to get tricky, there are bytecode obfuscators.

Answer (score 2):

No. And you can verify this by using DJ Java Decompiler, for example. If you also refer to the [Java Class File Format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html), you'll see there's no construct for storing comments.

Answer (score 1):

Comments aren't included in the `.class` files, so a decompiler won't be able to produce them.