# How to insert revision number of Java code file in to Java class file

Tags: java, version-control, cvs

Java code file contains @author and @version tags. version tag has information about the revision number of file. This information resides in comments. 
Is there any compilation flag or other mechanism available by which I can add this information to .class file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032147/does-java-include-comments-on-the-compiled-code

Comment: Short answer: javadoc is not processed by the compiler. Long answer: You could create an annotation (`public @interface Author`) with `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` (or `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`) and then just generate annotations from javadoc (with an own application).

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu I saw that question already. That's why I mentioned "any other mechanism" in my question.

Comment: @afk5min But will that add version info to .class file?
I'm not looking to generate javadoc from code file. I want that information in .class file.

Comment: An annotation with `RP CLASS/RUNTIME` will be written to the .class file as an Annotation element. `RP CLASS` annotation can be accessible to anything that can read a well-formed java class file (e.g. ASM4). `RP RUNTIME` annotations can also be accessed during runtime via `Test.class.getAnnotation(Author.class)`.

Comment: Who's downvoting this question. This is real problem not some homework

Comment: This forum seems to be hijacked by maniacs who, instead of providing solution to problem, closes the question.... I think moderators should take note of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
The compiler ignores JavaDoc as all other forms of comments.

Long answer:
You would need to write an application that would copy existing `@author AuthorName` and `@version VersionString` javadoc elements above the class/method declarations, such as:

```
@Author({"AuthorName", "OtherAuthor"})
@Version("VersionString")
public class Something [...] { [...] }
```

An example `Author` annotation could be:

```
@Author("afk5min")
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface Author {
  String[] value();
}
```

This way, each annotation is present in the resulting class file and may be accessed.

> 9.6.3.2. @Retention
>
> Annotations may be present only in source code, or they may be present in the binary form  of a class or interface. An annotation that is present in the binary form may or may not be available at run time via the reflection libraries of the Java SE platform. The annotation type java.lang.annotation.Retention is used to choose among these possibilities.

Additionally, `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` may be specified if you desire runtime access to annotations. The reflection API allows this:

```
Author.class.getAnnotation(Author.class).value()[0] -> "afk5min"
```

Answer (score 0):

One time, I modified my Ant build script to create a MANIFEST.MF file with the version number, amongst other information.

Here's the most recent MANIFEST.MF file,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 19.0-b09 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: gov.bop.svnreport.SVNReportMain
Built-By: Gilbert G. Le Blanc
Built-On: 20111109-1437
Version: 1.1.1
Specification-Title: Subversion Commit Report
Specification-Version: 1.1.1
Specification-Vendor: Federal Bureau of Prisons
Class-Path: svnkit.jar
```

Here's the JAR target from the Ant script.

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir = "${jar}"/>
    <echo>Jar directory - "${jar}"</echo>
    <manifest file="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="gov.bop.svnreport.SVNReportMain"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="svnkit.jar"/>
        <!-- This line puts your username into the manifest.
             Maybe you don't want to do that. -->
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="Gilbert G. Le Blanc"/>
        <attribute name="Built-On" value="${DSTAMP}-${TSTAMP}"/>
        <!-- This property was set by the svn-info task -->
        <!-- <attribute name="Revision" value="${svnrevision}"/> -->
        <!-- This property comes from the build.properties file -->
        <attribute name="Version" value="${app.version}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Title" value="Subversion Commit Report"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${app.version}"/>
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor" value="Federal Bureau of Prisons"/>
    </manifest>

    <jar jarfile="${jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar"
                manifest="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
            <fileset dir="${build}/">
                    <patternset refid="all-classes"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="." includes="${bin.includes}/"/>          
    </jar>
    <copy file="${jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" todir="${deploy}" />
    <copy file="${svnkit}" todir="${deploy}" />
</target>
```

I tried to get the Subversion version number into the MANIFEST.MF file, but I couldn't get that to work.

A problem with this method is that it only works when you execute the Java application from the JAR file.  If you try and pull these manifest properties from an IDE like Eclipse, `null` values are returned.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I'll look into this direction.